# How to only count words containing only A-Z and a-z?

Tags: perl

Okay, first of all, here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use open qw(:utf8 :std);

use utf8;

print "Which file do you want to search?\n";

$file = <>;

if ($file =~ /^\s*$/) {
    $file = "test.txt";
}

open (FILE, $file) or die("Could not open file.");

%hash;

while (<FILE>) {
    $hash{$_}++ for split /\W+/;
}

$count = 0;

for (sort {
        $hash{$b} <=> $hash{$a}
                  ||
           lc($a) cmp lc($b)
                  ||
              $a  cmp  $b
     } keys %hash )

{
    next unless /\w/;
    printf "%-20s %5d\n", $_, $hash{$_} if ($count <= 9);
    $count++;
}
```

I only want to count words containing only A-Z and a-z but this code also counts numbers. What must I do?

This is an example of the output:

```
Car                     18
5                       11
Test                    11
Task                    10
Perl                     7
School                   6
Hi                       5
Tired                    5
Word                     4
bye                      3
```

As you can see, the number 5 is listed which isn't supposed to happen.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! And yes, I did mean words that only contain letters :P A bit tired after writing code for several hours. I am new to perl so every little problem requires reading books and forums -.-'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
++$hash{$_} for grep /^[a-zA-Z]+\z/, split /\W+/;
```

Of course, you probably meant words that only contain letters.

```
++$hash{$_} for grep /^\pL+\z/, split /\W+/;
```

Comment: Why not `split /\Pl+/` ?

Comment: @Patrick J. S., Not equivalent. That would consider `abc` of `abc123 def` to be a word when the OP's code did not